# Dynamic checkboxes mutually exclusive

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to add checkboxes during the initialization of my Userform. They have to be mutually exclusive. I know about option buttons but I can't use them for my form.

For now, I can't set them to be mutually exclusive. They are in a frame and I've set their `.GroupName` property to be the same. This is where I don't understand why it won't work. I read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/checkbox-groupname-property-outlook-forms-script) which tells that "All check boxes with the same GroupName within a single container are mutually exclusive".

I've also tried this on a blank Userform with and without frames but I can always select more than one checkbox.

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: General concept is checkeboxes aren't exclusive, option button, are. Why can't you use option?

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ If a user selects one by mistake, you can't unselect them by click. This is why I chosed checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use code to achieve same functionality:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click(): Check_Just CheckBox1: End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click(): Check_Just CheckBox2: End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click(): Check_Just CheckBox3: End Sub

Sub Check_Just(CheckBox)
    'Disable false triggers when unchecking boxes
    If CheckBox.Value = False Or CheckBox.GroupName = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Uncheck all other control with same groupname
    Dim ctl As control
    For Each ctl In CheckBox.Parent.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then If ctl.GroupName = CheckBox.GroupName And Not ctl Is CheckBox Then ctl.Value = Unchecked
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm gonna try with this code, I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I added a typename check and now it works perfectly. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Yes, type check is needed. Edited my answer also.